# Parsing large amounts of text

Tags: c++, string, sockets, memory-leaks

To give a quick overview of the program
1.) Opens connection to a socket and reads data
2.) Splits the data at newline char
3.) Pushes data segments onto a queue to be processed in a separate thread.

I am using the curlpp library as it handles the authentication and DNS lookup. 
The queue is just a deque with mutexes for thread safety.

This is the method i am using right now.

```
std::string input;
size_t socketIO::dataCallBack(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb) {
    // Calculate the real size of the incoming buffer
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;

    //Append the new input to the old input
    input.append(ptr, realsize);

    //Find all the complete strings and push them to the queue
    size_t oldPosition = 0;
    size_t position = 0;
    position = input.find('\r', oldPosition);
    while (position != std::string::npos) {
        queueObject.push(input.substr(oldPosition, position))
        oldPosition = position + 1;
        position = input.find('\r', oldPosition);
    }

    //Save off the partial string as you'll get the rest of it on the next data callback
    input = input.substr(oldPosition);

    return realsize;
}
```

I have a few concerns.  I am having problems with memory leaks and valgrind is showing a major leak from this function.

```
==12867== 813,287,102 bytes in 390,337 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 359 of 359
==12867==    at 0x4C27CC1: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==12867==    by 0x5AA8D98: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x5AA9B64: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x5AA9D38: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x41E4F5: socketIO::write(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (basic_string.h:2006)
==12867==    by 0x509C657: utilspp::Functor<unsigned long, utilspp::tl::TypeList<char*, utilspp::tl::TypeList<unsigned long, utilspp::tl::TypeList<unsigned long, utilspp::NullType> > > >::operator()(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (Functor.hpp:106)
==12867==    by 0x509B6E4: curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::executeWriteFunctor(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (CurlHandle.cpp:171)
==12867==    by 0x509F509: curlpp::internal::Callbacks::WriteCallback(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long, curlpp::internal::CurlHandle*) (OptionSetter.cpp:47)
==12867==    by 0x4E3D667: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.1.1)
==12867==    by 0x4E5407B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.1.1)
==12867==    by 0x4E505A1: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.1.1)
==12867==    by 0x4E51A8F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.1.1)
==12867==    by 0x509A78B: curlpp::internal::CurlHandle::perform() (CurlHandle.cpp:52)
==12867==    by 0x5093A6B: curlpp::Easy::perform() (Easy.cpp:48)
==12867==    by 0x41EDC3: socketIO::processLoop() (socketIO.cpp:126)
```

What would you suggest to do.  I have considered using an istringstream, but I'm not sure how its memory allocation works and if it will reclaim memory that I've read already.  I have a problem in that I need to keep data around between callbacks, but to do it in a way that won't leak memory.

**UPDATE**
As requested more code.  I posted with the idea that more is better.

main.cpp

```
/**
 * The main driver for the twitter capture app.  Starts multiple threads for processors, 1 io thread and 2 db threads. One for user
 * information and the other for tweet information 
 */

#include "types.h"
#include "threadBase.h"
#include "socketIO.h"
#include "processor.h"
#include "dbTweetQueue.h"
#include "dbUserQueue.h"

#include <vector>


stringQueue twitToProc;
tweetQueue tweetQ;
userQueue userQ;
deleteQueue deleteQ;
std::vector<ThreadBase *> threadGroup;

std::string dbBase::dbUser(DBUSER);
std::string dbBase::dbURL(DBURL);
std::string dbBase::dbPass(DBPASS);

/*
 * Handle the signal for interupt
 */
void sigquit(int param)
{
    std::cout<<"Received sigquit"<<std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < threadGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        threadGroup[i]->interupt();
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try{
    //Setting the signal handler up.
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = sigquit;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &act, 0);


    int MaxThreads = 5;
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout<<"Usage: >"<<argv[0]<<" TwitterUserName TwitterPassWord"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Using Defaults: "<<TWITTERACCT<<" "<<TWITTERPASS<<std::endl;
    }

    // Create socketIO, and add it to the thread group
    if(argc == 3)
    {
        threadGroup.push_back(new socketIO(twitToProc, argv[1], argv[2]));
    }
    else
    {
        threadGroup.push_back(new socketIO(twitToProc));
    }


   // Create processorThreads and add them to the thread group
    for(int i = 0; i < MaxThreads; i++)
    {
        threadGroup.push_back(new processor(twitToProc, tweetQ, deleteQ, userQ));
    }

    //Create DB Threads and add them to the thread group.
    threadGroup.push_back(new dbTweetQueue(tweetQ, deleteQ));
    threadGroup.push_back(new dbUserQueue(userQ));


    // Start the threads
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < threadGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        threadGroup[i]->start();
    }

    // Join the threads
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < threadGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        threadGroup[i]->join();
    }

           } catch (std::exception & e) {
            std::cerr << e.what() <<  std::endl;
        } 

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < threadGroup.size(); i++)
    {
        threadGroup[i]->();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

threadBase.h

```
#ifndef _THREADBASE_H
#define _THREADBASE_H

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class ThreadBase
{
public:
    virtual void join() = 0;
    virtual void start() = 0;
    void interupt(){thread.interrupt();}
protected:
    boost::thread thread;

};



#endif  /* _THREADBASE_H */
```

socketIO.h

```
#ifndef _SOCKETIO_H
#define _SOCKETIO_H

#include "types.h"
#include "threadBase.h"

#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Multi.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Infos.hpp>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>


#define defaultRepeatInterval 10;

class socketIO: public ThreadBase {
private:
    int repeatInterval;
    double previousDownloadSize;
    int failCount;
    int writeRound;
    std::string userPassword;
    stringQueue&  queueObject;
    std::string input;


public:
    socketIO(stringQueue & messageQueue):
                queueObject(messageQueue)
    {
        userPassword.append(TWITTERACCT);
        userPassword.append(":");
        userPassword.append(TWITTERPASS);
    }

    socketIO(stringQueue & messageQueue, char* userName, char* password):
                queueObject(messageQueue)
    {
        userPassword.append(userName);
        userPassword.append(":");
        userPassword.append(password);
    }

    virtual ~socketIO();

    void join();
    void start();
    std::auto_ptr<curlpp::Easy> createRequest(int);



    void processLoop();
    size_t write(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb);
    int progress(double, double, double, double);

};

#endif  /* _SOCKETIO_H */
```

socketIO.cpp

```
#include "socketIO.h"

socketIO::~socketIO() {
}

/*
 * This method starts a new thread with the processLoop method
 */
void socketIO::start() {
    thread = boost::thread(&socketIO::processLoop, this);
}

/*
 * This method blocks waiting for the thread to exit
 */
void socketIO::join() {
    thread.join();
}

/*
 * The datacall back function for the open twitter connection.\
 */
size_t socketIO::write(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb) {
    // Calculate the real size of the incoming buffer
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    std::string temp;
    temp.append(input);
    temp.append(ptr, realsize);
    size_t oldPosition = 0;
    size_t position = 0;
    position = temp.find('\r', oldPosition);
    while (position != std::string::npos) {
        queueObject.push(temp.substr(oldPosition, position));
        ++writeRound;
        oldPosition = position + 1;
        position = temp.find('\r', oldPosition);
    }
    input = temp.substr(oldPosition);
    return realsize;
}

/*
 * The timed callback function, called every second, used to monitor that the connection is still receiving data
 * Return 1 if requesting break or data flow stops, 0 if continuing normally
 */
int socketIO::progress(double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow) {
    // Allows us to break out on interruption
    if (boost::this_thread::interruption_requested())
        return 1;

    if (dlnow == previousDownloadSize) {
        if (failCount < 15)
            failCount++;
        else {
            repeatInterval = repeatInterval * 2;
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        repeatInterval = 10;
        previousDownloadSize = dlnow;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
 * This method creates a new connection to the twitter service with the required settings
 */
std::auto_ptr<curlpp::Easy> socketIO::createRequest(int source) {
    //Reset the input buffer when the connection is made.
    input = std::string("");
    std::auto_ptr<curlpp::Easy> newRequest(new curlpp::Easy);

    curlpp::types::ProgressFunctionFunctor progressFunctor(this, &socketIO::progress);
    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::ProgressFunction(progressFunctor));

    curlpp::types::WriteFunctionFunctor functor(this, &socketIO::write);
    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteFunction(functor));

    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::FailOnError(true));
    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::NoProgress(0));
    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Verbose(true));
    newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::UserPwd(userPassword));


    //Code for debugging and using alternate sources
    std::string params = "track=basketball,football,baseball,footy,soccer";

    switch (source) {
        case 1: // Testing Locally
            newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("127.0.0.1:17000"));
            break;
        case 2: // Filtered
            newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"));
            newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(params));
            newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize(params.size()));
            break;
        case 3: //Twitter Main Stream
            newRequest->setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url("http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"));
            break;
    }

    return newRequest;
}


/*
 * The main method of the thread.  Creates a new instance of the request
 */
void socketIO::processLoop() {
    repeatInterval = defaultRepeatInterval;
    std::auto_ptr<curlpp::Easy> request;
    while (true) {
        try {
            previousDownloadSize = 0;
            failCount = 0;
            request.reset(createRequest(3));
            request->perform();
        } catch (curlpp::UnknowException & e) {
            std::cout << "Unknown Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (curlpp::RuntimeError & e) {
            std::cout << "Runtime Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        } catch (curlpp::LogicError & e) {
            std::cout << "Logic Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }


        if (boost::this_thread::interruption_requested())
            break;
        else
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(repeatInterval));
    }
}
```

types.h

```
#ifndef _TYPES_H
#define _TYPES_H

#include <string>
#include <concurrent_queue.hpp>

#define DBUSER "****"
#define DBPASS "****"
#define DBURL "****"
#define TWITTERACCT "****"
#define TWITTERPASS "****"

typedef struct tweet {
...
} tweet;

typedef struct user {
...
} user;


typedef concurrent_queue<std::string> stringQueue;
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> dbPair;
typedef concurrent_queue<dbPair> dbQueue;

typedef concurrent_queue<tweet> tweetQueue;
typedef concurrent_queue<user> userQueue;
typedef concurrent_queue<boost::int64_t> deleteQueue;

#endif  /* _TYPES_H */
```

concurrent_queue.hpp

```
#ifndef _CONCURRENT_QUEUE_
#define _CONCURRENT_QUEUE_

#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <deque>

template<typename Data>
class concurrent_queue
{
private:
    std::deque<Data> the_queue;
    mutable boost::mutex the_mutex;
    boost::condition_variable the_condition_variable;
public:
    void push(Data const& data)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        the_queue.push_back(data);
        lock.unlock();
        the_condition_variable.notify_one();
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        return the_queue.empty();
    }

    bool try_pop(Data& popped_value)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        if(the_queue.empty())
        {
            return false;
        }

        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.empty())
        {
            the_condition_variable.wait(lock);
        }

        popped_value=the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop_front();
    }

};

#endif  /* _CONCURRENT_QUEUE_ */
```

Comment: Is that all of the valvgrind backtrace? I don't see your code in it, but maybe I missed it. I just see libcurl and socketIO stuff. Further more you don't have a `new` call in your function, only `append`, which I would hope the STL implementation you are using got that down right.

Comment: Does socketIO ever get destructed? I am assuming that "std::string input" is a member of socketIO, is that correct?

Comment: \r is carriage return and network protocols (today) usually use \r\n or just \n for newlines.  This doesn't appear to cause your leaks, but perhaps it's a contributing issue?  You're sure the protocol you're following uses a single \r to terminate lines?

Comment: @Mic: socketIO doesn't get destructed until program termination and input is a member of socketIO  @Fred: The protocol I am using using a single '\r' as the message is allowed to contain '\n' in it.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: That is all the valgrind backtrace that valgrind provided.  Part of it is how the curl / curlpp library works.  I register the callback function as well as other parameters for the connection and then call perform().  This then creates the connection and does the callback when data is present.  I think that is why the valgrind output looks "funny".  The program has memory leaks running on both gentoo, and Ubuntu 10.4.

Comment: While I know it can be a lot of work, a complete (compilable) and short test case really helps us in answering, but, more importantly, can help you narrow down the problem.  Unfortunately, the above code isn't that. — Writing unit tests can help narrow things down.  Abstracting away the remote connection and using a fixed input sample, will, for example, make the test case that shows the leak more easily repeatable and more easily executed by others.

Comment: AFAICT you are pushing a lot of heap allocated objects in your ThreadGroup vector, but never deleting them. That would explain the memory leaks reported by valgrind.Of course, you may still have a problem with memory usage (not technically a leak) if you receive a lot of data, without a \r. This may be necessary, but if that does happen you should try to minimize copying and moving that data around, which is what happens when you call substr and assign strings to other strings.

Comment: You may also want to look into how other applications handle buffering of data and perhaps a datastructure which isn't just a block of contiguous memory (if you are expecting large amounts of data)

Comment: The problem is hard to reproduce in a small manner.  The program consumes about 5 gb of data a day, and in that time "leaks" about 1 gig.  The messages are short, normally somewhere around 1000 characters each, but never more than 2000 and is very consistent.  How can i ensure that the new strings are deleted correctly when they are removed from the queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I really have enough information to be certain of this answer, but here's my guess.

By looking at your valgrind stack for when the memory was allocated, you see:

```
==12867== 813,287,102 bytes in 390,337 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 359 of 359
==12867==    at 0x4C27CC1: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==12867==    by 0x5AA8D98: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x5AA9B64: ??? (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x5AA9D38: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&, unsigned long, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==12867==    by 0x41E4F5: socketIO::write(char*, unsigned long, unsigned long) (basic_string.h:2006)
```

That pretty much just means the string was created in your write-method. std::string, like most stl containers does not allocate anything on the heap until necessary, which in this case is when you append data to it.

Now, the memory is allocated and that's fine, but it is never deallocated because the destructor of the *std::string input* is never called. There could be a few reasons for this, but the most common are:

- You heap allocated socketIO and forgot to free it.
- You have virtual functions, but forgot a virtual destructor somewhere.

Comment: I don't know how to define this problem.  I'm unsure if its a memory leak or runaway memory, but either way it's a problem.  The program is meant to run capturing data for very long periods of time and as such it won't be destructed.

Answer (score 2):

`ThreadBase` does not have a virtual destructor.

The result of applying `delete` to `ThreadBase*` whenever the object pointed to is not a `ThreadBase` but a derived type is therefore **undefined**. In practice, it's often a leak, if any of the derived classes allocated memory (directly or indirectly).

```
class ThreadBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ThreadBase() {} // <-- There you go!

    virtual void join() = 0;
    virtual void start() = 0;

    void interupt() { thread.interrupt(); }

protected:
    boost::thread thread;
};
```

From the design point of view:

- avoid `protected` attributes, prefer providing methods to encapsulate their use.
- the NVI (Non-Virtual Interface) idiom stipulates that using methods that are both `public` and `virtual` is a bad idea (cannot check preconditions and postconditions for example), it's better using a public non-virtual method that will call a private virtual method for the implementation details stuff.
- you could probably have `ThreadBase` inherit privately from `boost::noncopyable` to document that it's not copyable.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am weighing in here rather late (more than a few months in fact) but in case others are following this thread, I have a similar issue and I've managed to trace it down to the curlpp libraries.

That being said, I'm far from a C++ expert and I'm pretty sure it is the manner in which I'm using the libraries.  They say they use an RAII style of cleaning up memory but even explicitly creating and destroying option settings within my request (that is re-used during my program's execution), I still see a serious growth in the process's memory footprint.

When I remove the calls to the curlpp libraries, my program runs within a very static as far as it's memory requirements.  Most of the examples they provide are simple programs that have main() do something and exit, so it's not as straightforward to create a daemon like executable that uses a class with a Easy HTTPClient (what I'm using) that is created at instantiation and is re-used throughout the program's execution.

Comment: I originally thought I had was having the same problem, but i haven't noticed any of the problems you noted.  While i do connect and maintain a connection to one specific host and I'm not opening 100's or 1000's of connections a day, in a period of 2 months I have opened (and closed) 6634 connections without any noticeable memory leak.  Memory consumption has been steady since the program was started.  I haven't done extensive testing of the libraries, but at least in my situation memory leaks haven't been a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be elsewhere entirely or in combination with this code and elsewhere.

There is no memory leak in the code you've posted.  There's a possibility you have transformed the code for posting on SO that has left out important details.  For example, you've left out locking the queue (which you mention is required and I believe you actually do), which could lead to corruption and leaks.  Another example is the input variable: is it really a global or is it a data member?  [Mic mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686378/parsing-large-amounts-of-text/4686532#4686532) several more potential errors which may or may not be transcription errors.

We really need a complete, compilable example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have posted most of the code for this program including the queue implementation.  Input is a data member of a class that has a lifetime of approximately the entire program.